# Telegram track forwarding and storing

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

**Short:**
Is there any way to detect if a user stores or forwards a message (e.g. a video) in a channel?

**Long:**
I am completely new to programming for Telegram (although am a programmer). So have no idea about the tools that are provided by Telegram's API. I actually found nothing related to this issue browsing the web and Telegram documentations. So I thought someone might have an experience with it.

The scenario is that a client of mine is running a virtual teaching system on Telegram and her problem is that the added members to the channel are able to forward the teaching videos to other persons out of the channel, who have not actually paid the fee. Now is there any work around on earth for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can't track user in Telegram, remember this IM is very care about privacy.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it a Bot rather than a channel, you can create bots with a bot in telegram called botfather search it and consider making a bot instead of a channel

Comment: Could you explain more in detail how a bot can handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

there isn't any way to track users to see if they forward or save the videos.
you can only do one of these:

- create a bot using telegram api (not telegram bot api) and then send videos as a self destructing message to each user.
- or put the videos on a website which only registered users can login and watch.